# Incorrect output when indexing into a string

Tags: c++, string, char

I have some code like this:

```
string s = "ab";
s[0] = '1';
s[1] = '2';
cout << s << "." << s[0] << "." << s[1] << "." << endl;
```

It gives me what I want, which is `12.1.2.`

But the following code:

```
string ss = "";
ss[0] = '1';
ss[1] = '2';
cout << ss << "." << ss[0] << "." << ss[1] << "." << endl;
```

It doesn't give me what I want. Its output is `.1.2.`

Why is that? I thought it should be `12.1.2.`

*BTW, I'm doing that with QTcreator 5.4. Does that matter?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, `operator[]` simply accesses the character at the specified index, it doesn't add characters to the string (use `push_back` for that). If the index is greater than the string length this is undefined behavior.

Comment: A good debug compiler would alert you to your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string ss = "";
ss[0] = '1';
ss[1] = '2';
cout << ss << "." << ss[0] << "." << ss[1] << "." << endl;
```

This looks like undefined behavior. Perhaps you should use [`at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/) to trigger the [`out_of_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/) exception :)

```
string ss = "";
ss.at(0) = '1';
ss.at(1) = '2';
cout << ss << "." << ss[0] << "." << ss[1] << "." << endl;
```

It results in the following on OS X (because I am *not* catching the exception):

```
$ ./cxx-test.exe
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
Abort trap: 6
```

You can fix it with something like:

```
string ss = "  ";    // two blanks spaces
```

Or:

```
string ss;
ss.resize(2);
```